# Вывод статуса служб. C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть массив с названиями служб. И есть цикл foreach, который проверяет статус служб. А ещё много надписей: label9,label10,label11... Вот я получил статус службы, как её статус вывести в отдельную надпись?

Код который использую:

```
string[] services = { "PolicyAgent", "IKEEXT", "WdiServiceHost" ,"WdiSystemHost", "wscsvc" ,"wuauserv" };
            foreach (string i in services)
            {
                ServiceController servis = new ServiceController(i);
                if(servis.Status.ToString() == "Running")
                {
                    //код
                }
                if(servis.Status.ToString() == "Stopped")
                {
                    //код
                }
            }
```

Comment: `servis.Status.ToString() == "Running"` - это прям извращение какое-то) `Enum` не для этого были созданы... А по вопросу - ну так ищите нужный `lable` и задавайте ему текст. Какой нужный? А нам по чем знать...

Comment: А как его искать? Если я знаю только как прописывать текст конкретному lable.

Comment: Ну у вас наверно должна быть какая-то логика поиска, не? По тегу, по имени, еще как-то. Вот по этой логике и ищите. Если это WPF, то вовсе не должно быть lable...

Comment: А что за приложение? Winforms, WPF? Вообще не надо кучу контролов создавать, для этого есть списки и таблицы.

Comment: WinForms. А в списке вроде нельзя изменить цвет одной строки.